# OCMock andReturn for different value based on the same mock instance, unexpected return value.

Tags: ios, ocmock

See #if 0...#endif, if enable then the mock works as expected, return 1 when invoking method preferencesGeneralUnits, if disable then the mock still returns the previous value 0 despite we ask him to return 1.

My question, is it OCMock bug? Or is it expected usage for OCMock?  Thank you.

Bad for both 2.0.1 and build from latest source code.

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
- (void) testFormattedDistanceValueWithMeters{
    id mockSettings = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[TnSettings class]];
    id mockClientModel = [TnClientModel createMockClientModel];
    [[[mockClientModel stub] andReturn:mockSettings] settings];

    [[[mockSettings stub] andReturn:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]] preferencesGeneralUnits];

    NSNumber *meters = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.9];
    distance = [NSString formattedDistanceValueWithMeters:meters];
    STAssertEqualObjects(distance, @"0.9", @"testformattedEndTimeForTimeInSeconds failed");

    //--------------See here---------------------
    #if 0
    mockSettings = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[TnSettings class]];
    mockClientModel = [TnClientModel createMockClientModel];
    [[[mockClientModel stub] andReturn:mockSettings] settings];
    #endif
    [[[mockSettings stub] andReturn:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]] preferencesGeneralUnits];

    meters = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];
    distance = [NSString formattedDistanceValueWithMeters:meters];
    STAssertEqualObjects(distance, @"3.3", @"testformattedEndTimeForTimeInSeconds failed");

    [TnClientModel releaseInstance];
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the code. Where is preferencesGeneralUnits even called? I see no call to mockSettings in the code. It seems there are some global variables in play somewhere. If that's the case, chances are that if you don't recreate the model (#if 0 case) you are still using the old instance with the mock that has been instructed to stub a method to return 0. Stubbing the same method to return a different value has no effect afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, use the old instance it will always return the old expect value. If you want to return new expected value, you should use new instance, reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik Doernenburg's explain is reasonable.